# Hover background change based on theme selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing a website with two themes Light and Dark. I want to change the hover background of links based on the theme selected. What is the way to change the background of hover using CSS?

on a White background, I have a light blue hover background to link.
[image]

on a Dark background, I want to have hover background transparent to link.

[image]

I tried with changing class with the theme but I am not sure how to write selector for hover with the class change.

```
<a href='' className={theme ? ' top_section_link ' : ' top_section_link_dark '}>
```

CSS for hover on the link. It works fine for light theme but I don't know how to write selector if I change the class.

```
.lead a:hover {
  color: #2161f2;
  background: #f0f4fe;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2161f2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome Ravikant! In order to answer your question in the most helpful way, it would help the SO community if you could share some of your code and what you've tried.

Comment: can you share the code you have tried in achieving this please?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I added the code snippet. If you need anything more, please tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the hover css code dependent on the link. So instead of

```css
.lead a:hover { /* ... */ }
```

write it this way:

```css
.lead a.top_section_link:hover { /* Light/Default Theme Hover */ }
.lead a.top_section_link_dark:hover { /* Dark Theme Hover */ }
```

Another way would be to only switch a class on the `body` tag. This allows switching the theme without checking the current theme everywhere in your JS code:

```css
body.light-theme a:hover{}
body.dark-theme a:hover{}

/* with other elements: */
body.light-theme button{}
body.light-theme button:hover{}

body.dark-theme button{}
body.dark-theme button:hover{}
```

Choosing this way, `SCSS` would make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

To target the link using the theme class names you can use `a.top_section_link:hover` or `a.top_section_link_dark:hover`.

```css
.lead a:hover {
  color: #2161f2;
  background: #f0f4fe;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2161f2;
}

.lead a.top_section_link_dark:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lead">
  <a href="" class="top_section_link">Link</a>
  <a href="" class="top_section_link_dark">Link</a>
</div>
```